# why typescript disallow call concat in string | string[] type?

Tags: javascript, typescript, type-systems, duck-typing

```ts
const s: string = 'foo';

const pass1 = (origin: string) => origin.concat(s);
const pass2 = (origin: string[]) => origin.concat(s);

type S = string | string[];

const error = (origin: S) => origin.concat(s);
```

The code above. I can call `concat` in a `string` or `string[]` type. So why TypeScript disallow call `concat` in `string | string[]` type?

The error is:

```
Cannot invoke an expression whose type lacks a call signature.
Type '((...strings: string[]) => string) | { (...items: ConcatArray<string>[]): string[]; (...items: (s...'
has no compatible call signatures.
```

Because they have different return type? But I think TS can infer `error`'s type is `S`. Is it a intentional design? If it is, why?

Comment: The good news is we can do this from TS 3.3. Also it need some improvement. Such as, `const ret = error('msg')`, what's the type of `ret`? TS infer it's `S`, but it should be `string`.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Because while the `concat` method is common between the two types it has a very different signature between the two, so Typescript can't really merge the declarations of the methods. While not ideal you can use a type guard to discern between the two types:

```
const s: string = 'foo';
type S = string | string[];

const error = (origin: S) => typeof origin === 'string' ?
    origin.concat(s) :
    origin.concat(s);
```

Or just assert as `any` :

```
const s: string = 'foo';
type S = string | string[];

const error = (origin: S) =>  (origin as any).concat(s) as S
```

There is also the option of transforming the union of signatures into an intersection of signatures. This may work well in some cases but not in others:

```
const s: string = 'foo';
type S = string | string[];

type UnionToIntersection<U> = 
(U extends any ? (k: U)=>void : never) extends ((k: infer I)=>void) ? I : never

function mergeSignature<T, K extends keyof T> (value: T, method: K) : UnionToIntersection<T[K]>{
    return ((...args: any[]) => (value[method] as any as Function).apply(value, args)) as any;
}

const error = (origin: S) => mergeSignature(origin, 'concat')(s);
```

Comment: I prefer type guard way. Thank you. Why TS cannot merge the result type in this case? I can write a function which may return `T1` or `T2`, but I do not need declare the function return type as `T1 | T2` explicitly, TS can infer it.

Comment: There is a discussion here as to why they don't do this https://github.com/Microsoft/TypeScript/issues/7294

Comment: I think they know about that issue, after all, they commented there ;)

Comment: Yes, I have read that issue before I ask this question in SOF. I understand it's difficult to handle deep call in a union type, it's hand to track what the union type consists of, such as curry function. But in my case, it's just a one level calling.  It's a design trade-off, but can implement. Right?

Comment: @merito probably it can be implemented, in some limited way. My guess is that if they can't implement it in a consistent way they would rather not do it, but I'm not on the team maintaining the compiler so I can't really say. The GitHub discussion is definitely the place where you can comment and get the team's attention that this is an issue for many people.

Comment: @merito added a new workaround that transforms the signature union to an intersection of sigantures making it callable